# Unable to get css width property for image

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to receive the css width of a group of images. For example, I have a css rule such as

```
#myDiv img{
   width: 100px;
}
```

and in $(document).ready() I have

```
console.log($("#myDiv img").css("width")); //prints 'undefined'
console.log($("#myDiv img").width());      //prints 'null'
```

How do I get at this css value? Thanks!

Edit:
I was loading the images dynamically after trying to get at the css value, and I did not know that jquery required an element to be present. Is there no way to get at the value before loading an image?

Comment: is the image present in the dom (and is it loaded?) ?

Comment: gion_13 you are a legend. I was loading in the images on the next line. If I do the same logs after I load them I get correct values. However, is there a way to get at that value before the images are loaded? That would be really helpful. Joseph, I am writing in the images with html(), all it is is <img src = "url" alt = "image" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If .css('width') returns undefined, and .width() returns null, that means there are no elements matching the selector "#myDiv img" on the page. For jQuery to access that property, one of those images has to actually exist in the page (i.e., you can't ask jQuery "what would the width of an element like this be?").

I'm guessing you are adding images dynamically to that div, and none exist when your script runs. Either that, or there's just some misspelling involving #myDiv.

Comment: You guess correctly. Is there a way to get at that value before the images are added?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure html is something like

```
<div id="myDiv"> 
  <img src="/nyan.gif" /> 
</div>
```

because it works for me

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/556f9/1